# Differences between getting a value in a class with instance constructors and a class filled with const fields

Tags: asp.net

I've got an example project. There is a config class which I need to set my id and key.

```
public class Config
    {
        #region Fields
        private static string partner = "";
        private static string key = "";
        #endregion

        static Config()
        {
            //↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ Config your identity ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

            //PartnerID (Begins with digits 2088)
            partner = "";

            //Veryfy Code 
            key = "";

            //↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
        }

        #region Properties

        public static string Partner
        {
            get { return partner; }
            set { partner = value; }
        }

        public static string Key
        {
            get { return key; }
            set { key = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

So methods in other class can get my ID and Key like：

```
string _partner = Config.Partner.Trim();
string _key = Config.Key.Trim();
public bool Verify(SortedDictionary<string, string> inputPara, string notify_id, string _partner, string _key )
{
  //...
}
```

My question is, **what if I change the Config.cs as**:

```
public class testConfig
    {
        public const string Partner = ""; //Config your PartnerId
        public const string Key = ""; //Config your Key
    }
```

Since my partnerID, Key never change if everything goes well, and they only need to be compiled at the very beginning so that method in other class can get these two value. **Calling Config.Key.Trim(), the results are the same. Why not use a class filled with const fields like I just write?**

Answer (score 0):

No difference.

Try debugging both cases, you'll see that variables are set almost the same way.